# C - Nested for loop - not understanding behavior

Tags: c, loops, nested-for-loop

Excuse this noob question, I've tried to read other questions and answers but I just don't get it. I don't get the logic of execution in a nested for loop.
ef

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)

    {

        printf(" ");
        printf("second");
        printf(" ");

    }

  printf("first");

}
```

Output when n = 4:

```
first second first second  second first second  second  second first
```

I have no idea why the output is first, second - and then second second.

Would anyone care to explain? I've tried staring at the screen for 2 hours - and reading the 4 first google hits on nested for loops flowcharts and it's just too complex..

Thanks

Edit: as Weather Vane suggested I added a \n after 'first' to make it clearer.

Now output is:

```
first
 second first
 second  second first
 second  second  second first
```

Comment: the inner `j` loop loops first 0 times (because `i` is `0`), then 1 times (`i` is 1), then 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: Play computer on paper, every row a step, columns for I, j, and the printed result

Comment: It would be clearer if you add a newline as `printf("first\n");` It would show that the output isn't grouped as your supposition "first, second - and then second second". It is "first", "second first", "second second first" etc.

Comment: You might benefit from stepping through the code using a debugger.

Comment: Ahh, thank you - that helped make it clearer. See edit

Comment: The 3 lines could be reduced to `printf(" second ");`

Comment: Short version: `first` prints *after* the execution of the nested `second` loop, and that includes the first encounter of that loop which prints *nothing* because `j<i` when `i` is zero is already false.

Comment: Maybe the comments/answers to this might help, or possibly you could just ask them in class: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70996034/758133

Answer (score -1):

For each iteration of the outer loop (4 iterations, `i` varying from `0` to `3` inclusively), the inner loop iterates `i` times (`j` varying from `0` to `i-1`).

Hence for the first iteration, the inner loop runs `0` times, so no output before the `printf("first")`, then the second iteration causes the inner loop to run once and output `second` before the `printf("first")`, etc.

- first iteration: `first`,
- second iteration:  `second first`,
- third iteration:  `second  second first`,
- fourth iteration:  `second  second  second first`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

So if I understand correctly - J will only be incremented (via j++) after the outer loop is completed?

Comment: Not exactly: `j` is incremented at the end of each iteration of the **inner** loop and `i` is incremented at the end of the **outer** loop.